# Button with OnTouchListener that continuously does something while held down in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a noob to Android Studio, but am creating an application for a class for school. It is a max bench press calculator. I would like to make it so that when the increase or decrease weight button is held down, then the weight will continuously go up or down. I saw a couple of questions on this, but they were very confusing and weren't very well explained. I would rather not put code in that I don't know how it works, just to make the application run. Thanks!!

Comment: Damn! keep on touch listener inside oncreate method

Comment: Or implement it on Acitivy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such an effect by creating the button then setting it's onTouchListener to call certain methods when certain types of touch events are detected on the button. For example:

```
increaseWeightButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent mEvent) {
        if (mEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            startIncreasingWeight();
        else if (mEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            stopIncreasingWeight();
        return false;
    }
});
```

**edit:** Can you try putting the button.setOnTouchListener code just after creating the button in the onCreate() rather than outside?

Comment: is there anyway you could provide the entire code? There are many things that are underlined that I don't know why they are and I was wondering if I had to implement OnTouchListener in the public class main activity or what else I need to do. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No you don't have to implement, if you use the above code

Comment: Why is setOnTouchListener in red, OnTouchListener underlined in red, atOverride underlined in red, view in red, mEvent in red, and motion event underlined in red? I am being serious here lol. @Hussain ID

Comment: How are you creating the button? If you are instantiating a button from the class' layout XML you would write something like `Button increaseWeightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increaseButton);` in the activity's onCreate() method. Then you can set that button's OnTouchListener.

Comment: Please upload some screenshot

Comment: @MarkOrmerod I did that and everything is still underlined.

Comment: Also make sure that you import the relevant classes. Can you provide a screenshot or otherwise provide more code?

Comment: This is what I imported:    import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;       @MarkOrmerod

Comment: Try putting the button.setOnTouchListener code just after creating the button in the onCreate() code-block.